# How to lookup a individual item in Falcor

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I am having trouble figuring out how to structure routes for retrieving individual records. For example, lets say I have these routes:

```
itemsById[{integers:itemIds}]["id"]["name"]
userItems[{integers:itemIndices}]
```

So, the `userItems` route looks up the relevant item data in the `itemsById` route. This is fine for the **list** view of my app, however, I'm not sure how to define a route for the **show** view (which displays an individual item).

I suppose if I was on the **list** view I could store the index of the item that the user clicks on then lookup that index up in the `itemsById` route but the user might browse directly to the the **show** view route meaning I've no way to know the `itemsById` index.

I was thinking I could define a route to return the individual item:

```
userItem[{integers:itemId}]
```

This route takes the `itemId` as an argument then looks it up in the `itemsById` but this doesn't really seem right since Falcor suggests you shouldn't be working with IDs.

I'm likely missing something. Does anyone know what the correct approach is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close. As I understand, this would be your individual item lookup route:

```
itemsById[{keys:itemIds}][{keys:props}]
```

`itemIds` would be passed to your router as an array of item IDs. If the user is looking at a single-item detail view then the browser's URL might contain something like this: `/items/7bca23`. So on the client you'd do `model.get('itemsById.7bca23.name')` for example to grab the name of that item.

Meanwhile, for a list view you'd have a route like this:

```
itemsByIndex[{integers:indices}]
```

`indices` would be passed to your router as a series of numbers. On the client you'd do `model.get('itemsByIndex[0..20].name')`. Then from that route you'd return an array of objects like this:

```
{
  path: [ 'itemsByIndex', 0 ],
  value: { $type: 'ref', value: [ 'itemsById', '7bca23' ] }
}
```

Falcor will jump over to the `itemsById` route during that same request to provision the rest of the requested graph fragment.

Comment: Thanks for that. I kind of figured I might have to interact with the itemsById route directly - but I wasn't sure if it was good practice. Seems like the best option.